# Django: csrf verification error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, csrf, django-csrf

GET request:

```
<WSGIRequest
path:/contact,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'__utma': '96992031.1421967427.1405088230.1405685996.1405688035.8',
 '__utmb': '96992031.3.10.1405688035',
 '__utmc': '96992031',
 '__utmz': '96992031.1405088230.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
 'djdt': 'hide'},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': '',
 u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'RRNKQhMUwb2blNVeLxV61A8gqTbuFXya',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'djdt=hide; __utma=96992031.1421967427.1405088230.1405685996.1405688035.8; __utmb=96992031.3.10.1405688035; __utmc=96992031; __utmz=96992031.1405088230.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8000',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36',
 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/contact',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': 57435,
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1',
 'SERVER_PORT': '8000',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Werkzeug/0.9.6',
 'werkzeug.request': <BaseRequest 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact' [GET]>,
 'werkzeug.server.shutdown': <function shutdown_server at 0x25876e0>,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7f72b9132270>,
 'wsgi.input': <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f72b0132cd0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

Post request:

```
<WSGIRequest
path:/contact,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {u'city': [u'London'], u'first_name': [u'', u'', u''], u'future-notices-name': [u''], u'email_psp': [u'm'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'RRNKQhMUwb2blNVeLxV61A8gqTbuFXya'], u'email': [u''], u'wfax': [u'+44 (0)']}>,
COOKIES:{'__utma': '96992031.1421967427.1405088230.1405685996.1405688035.8',
 '__utmb': '96992031.3.10.1405688035',
 '__utmc': '96992031',
 '__utmz': '96992031.1405088230.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
 'csrftoken': 'RRNKQhMUwb2blNVeLxV61A8gqTbuFXya',
 'djdt': 'hide'},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '627',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'RRNKQhMUwb2blNVeLxV61A8gqTbuFXya',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'djdt=hide; __utma=96992031.1421967427.1405088230.1405685996.1405688035.8; __utmb=96992031.3.10.1405688035; __utmc=96992031; __utmz=96992031.1405088230.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); csrftoken=RRNKQhMUwb2blNVeLxV61A8gqTbuFXya',
 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8000',
 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/contact',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': 57438,
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1',
 'SERVER_PORT': '8000',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Werkzeug/0.9.6',
 'werkzeug.request': <BaseRequest 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact' [POST]>,
 'werkzeug.server.shutdown': <function shutdown_server at 0x7f72b0128aa0>,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7f72b9132270>,
 'wsgi.input': <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f72b02500d0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(cd))
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

The form looks like:

```
<form id="notice_form" action="/contact" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

...

I am trying to submit a form but i get a 403 forbidden error.
Inspecting the get/post request i can see that the csrftoken cookie is the same in both requests. Then why is it still giving me that error ? :(

Comment: Can you post the `<form>` HTML snippet?

Comment: i edited my post to include a part of the form (its being used the usual way, nothing different).

Comment: Did you enabled CSRF middleware?

Comment: yeah, its in my settings (django.middleware.csrf.CsrfMiddleware)

Comment: Can you take a look at your logs? I can see one error `'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7f72b9132270>,` but can't tell what or why it is exactly.

Comment: Check the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it
Speicifialy check:
`In the corresponding view functions, ensure that the 'django.core.context_processors.csrf' context processor is being used. Usually, this can be done in one of two ways:

Use RequestContext, which always uses 'django.core.context_processors.csrf' (no matter what your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting). If you are using generic views or contrib apps, you are covered already, since these apps use RequestContext throughout.`

Comment: Did you set any of these in your settings; `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django documentation (since I nearly never use function based views):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it

> In the corresponding view functions, ensure that the
>   'django.core.context_processors.csrf' context processor is being used.
>   Usually, this can be done in one of two ways:
>
> Use RequestContext, which always uses
>   'django.core.context_processors.csrf' (no matter what your
>   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting). If you are using generic views
>   or contrib apps, you are covered already, since these apps use
>   RequestContext throughout.

The problem is that you are using HttpResponse which does not utilize the RequestContext, so either you need to move to another solution or exempt the view from csrf (I would not prefer that).
If you are using this as an ajax request make sure you implement:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: nothing changes even if i use `render` or `render_to_response`(with the RequestContext) :(